# export to excel where datetime only date

Tags: delphi, excel, delphi-7, dbgrid

У меня в dbgrd столбец "дата и время" в формате datetime мне нужно чтобы при export to excel она отображала столбец "дата и время" только дату

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *нужно чтобы при export to excel она отображала столбец "дата и время" только дату* Уточните - в Excel В ДАННЫХ должна быть дата со временем, но отображается только дата, или сами данные не должны содержать компоненту времени? Первое решается форматированием ячеек, второе - обрезкой данных при передаче.

Comment: в Excel должно быть только дата

Comment: Значит, надо выполнять соотв. преобразование данных при экспорте (ну или перед экспортом). Скажем, с помощью RecodeTime...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if(dbgrd1.Columns[col].Visible=True) then begin
      if dbgrd1.Columns[col].FieldName='DEALDATE' then sline := sline + FormatDateTime('dd/MM/yyyy', qry1.FieldByName(dbgrd1.Fields[col].FieldName).AsDateTime) + #9 else
      sline := sline + qry1.FieldByName(dbgrd1.Fields[col].FieldName).AsString + #9;
    end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Экспорт в Excel осуществляется вручную или при помощи какого-то компонента/рутины?

Если первое - то проблемы нет: в комментариях уже предложили варианты решений. Можно и так:

```
DateToStr(StrToDateTime(yourdatevar));
```

Если же второе, то возможны варианты: невидимая копия dbgrid, в которой формат колонки изменен (если dbgrid целиком экспортируется), невидимая копия dbgrid, в которой только один столбец (если экспорт по столбцам). Эту невидимую копию и отдавать на экспорт.

Второй вариант подойдёт и для "ленивых": когда не хочется переписывать или разбираться в коде. Хотя такой подход порочен.

Answer (score 0):

Найди в какую колонку сохраняется дата и к ней применяй:

```
FormatDateTime('dd.mm.yy', StrToDateTime(mydate));
```

Comment: ExcelApp.WorkBooks[1].WorkSheets['Posishaimost'].Columns[2].ColumnWidth := 15; в какую часть надо вставить Formatdatetime ('dd.mm.yy',strtodatatime (mydate) ); ???

Comment: Это ширина задается

Comment: `ExcelApp.WorkBooks[1].WorkSheets['Posishaimost'].Columns[2].NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"` Но нужно понимать, что время всё равно в данных будет присутствовать - просто оно не отображается. Это может повлиять на расчёты (например, при группировке в сводной таблице).

Comment: Он выше говорил что это ему не подходит

Comment: Напиши цикл переберающий датасет